# Rails/SQL: find statistics about a belongs_to relation

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, postgresql, activerecord, logic

I have the following models

```
class Project
  has_many :contributions
end

class Contributor
  has_many :contributions
end

class Contribution
  belongs_to :contributor
  belongs_to :project
end
```

I'm trying to find how many contributors contributed in how many projects and sort by number of projects contributed to.

Example:

```
- Person 1 made contribution to Project 1
- Person 1 made contribution to Project 2
- Person 2 made contribution to Project 1
- Person 2 made contribution to Project 3
- Person 2 made contribution to Project 4
- Person 3 made contribution to Project 4
- Person 3 made contribution to Project 5
```

In this case

```
- Person 1 made 2 contributions in 2 seperate projects.
- Person 2 made 3 contributions in 3 seperate projects.
- Person 3 made 2 contributions in 2 seperate projects.
```

which means

```
- 2 people made 2 contributions
- 1 person made 3 contributions
```

Result is: `{ 2 => 2, 1 => 3 }`

Here is what I did:

```
Contributor.joins(:contributions).order("count(contributions.id) asc").group("contributor.id").count
```

This gives me how many contributions by each contributor, but not what I'm looking for.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
Contributor.joins(:contributions).order("count(contributions.id) asc").group("contributor.id").count.group_by{|i| i.last}.map{|a| [a.last.count,a.first]}
```

Comment: Is this useful for you ?

Answer (score 1):

```
# First, you need to count the distinct contributions for every contributor

contributors_info = Contributor.joins(:contributions).group("contributors.id").count("DISTINCT contributions.id")

   (0.4ms)  SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT contributions.id) AS count_distinct_contributions_id, contributors.id AS contributors_id FROM "contributors" INNER JOIN "contributions" ON "contributions"."contributor_id" = "contributors"."id" GROUP BY contributors.id

=> {1=>2, 2=>3, 3=>2}
```

You want your result be like this:

> - 2 people made 2 contributions
> - 1 person made 3 contributions
> - Result is: { 2 => 2, 1 => 3 }

But if there is another person made 4 contributions, your result will be like: `{ 2 => 2, 1 => 3, 1 => 4 }`, which is not a valid hash. That means you have to change the result construction, I suggest you use the `contribution_count` as the key, and people count as the value, since `contribution_count` will be unique.

```
# Then, use the previous information to get how many people made how many contributions

contributors_info.reduce({}) do |result, (_, contribution_count)|
  result[contribution_count] = (result[contribution_count] ||= 0) + 1
  result
end

# two contributions => 2 people, three contributions => 1 person
=> {2=>2, 3=>1}
```